# Complications of words

Tags: discussion

When I came to this website, I wanted to see logic debates, which I saw immediately. However, people use such complicated words and terms, including programming like terms, that I have no idea how to contribute. Is there a place for simple people like me? Thanks!

Comment: Are there logical discussions that use plain hard logic from one's own thoughts rather than someone else?

Comment: It would fit on meta; and there is a tag for logic - though I'm not sure what kind of logic puzzles you're thinking of; stuff such as Zeno's paradox of Achilles and the Tortoise or the Cretan Liar paradox are part of the narrative of philosophy as well as logic and more besides.

Answer (score 2):

Asking simple questions is OK and encouraged, as long as they are [on topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and have not been asked before. You could mention that you don't have an academical background, or whatever is the reason that you are not looking for complicated answers.

For writing answers, it may be more difficult. We can't force people to use easier language. So, you'll have to look for questions that are more or less on your level.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Philosophy.SE!

I would say a couple things:

First, given two answers that explain an idea, the simpler one is the better: if you ask a question, award the accepted answer points to the easier to understand one. If you come across questions on the site, upvote answers that are simpler to understand.

Second, if you spend much time on this site, you will come across things that you don't know about. Philosophy by its nature deals with difficult and subtle points - it is not expected that you would know any of these before participating, but seems like if you spend much time on this site it will because you want to learn about these ideas.